# How to convert the WordPress meta box Page Attributes->Page Template dropdown to radio buttons?

Tags: templates, metabox, page-attributes

I would like to be able to change the Page Attribute "Templates" dropdown to radio buttons, to allow me to have corresponding thumbnails next to them.

I have already removed and replaced the Page Attributes meta box on functions.php, as per below:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse44966_add_meta_box' );
function wpse44966_add_meta_box( $post_type ){ 
    remove_meta_box(
        'pageparentdiv',
        'page',
        'side');
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse44966-meta-box',
        'page' == $post_type ? __('Page Style Templates') : __('Attributes'),
        'wpse44966_meta_box_cb', 
        'page', 
        'side', 
        'low');
}
```

I am then able to call back the "Templates" dropdown in my own meta box - I have also included the *page_template_dropdown function* (renamed '*page_template_dropdown_show_it*').

```
function page_template_dropdown_show_it( $default = '', $post_type = 'page' ) {
    $templates = get_page_templates( null, $post_type );
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach ( array_keys( $templates ) as $template ) {
        $selected = selected( $default, $templates[ $template ], false );
        echo "\n\t<option value='" . esc_attr( $templates[ $template ] ) . "' $selected>" . esc_html( $template ) . '</option>';
    }
}

function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post ){
    echo 'Please select from the below'; 
    if ( count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) > 0 && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) :
        $template = ! empty( $post->page_template ) ? $post->page_template : false;  ?>
        <p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper"><label class="post-attributes-label" for="page_template"><?php _e( 'Template' ); ?></label><?php do_action( 'page_attributes_meta_box_template', $template, $post ); ?></p>
        <select name="page_template" id="page_template">
            <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title', __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
            <option value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?></option>
            <?php page_template_dropdown_show_it( $template, $post->post_type ); ?>
        </select>
    <?php endif;
}
```

However, when I then amend both *page_template_dropdown_show_it* and *wpse44966_meta_box_cb* to show radio buttons, the changes are applied visually but nothing happens when you select them?

```
function page_template_dropdown_show_it( $default = '', $post_type = 'page' ) {
    $templates = get_page_templates( null, $post_type );
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach ( array_keys( $templates ) as $template ) {
        $checked = checked( $default, $templates[ $template ], false );
        echo "\n\t<input type='radio' name='page_template' value='" . esc_attr( $templates[ $template ] ) . "' $checked>" . esc_html( $template );
    }
}

function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post ){
    echo 'Please select from the below'; 
    if ( count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) > 0 && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) :
        $template = ! empty( $post->page_template ) ? $post->page_template : false;  ?>
        <p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper"><label class="post-attributes-label" for="page_template"><?php _e( 'Template' ); ?></label><?php do_action( 'page_attributes_meta_box_template', $template, $post ); ?></p>
            <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title', __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
            <input type='radio' name='page_template' value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?>
            <?php page_template_dropdown_show_it( $template, $post->post_type ); ?>
    <?php endif;
}
```

It's obviously not as simple as a straight swap-out (as it isn't working), but the only thing that I can see that is missing is now there is nothing carrying the id="page_template", whereas before it was included in the below:

```
<select name="page_template" id="page_template">
```

Comment: Since the problem seems to be with the values being saved, or not, have you debugged the variables posted vs the save functions?

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that I was correct that the issue was that the id "page_template" was no longer being passed.

To solve this, all I have done is applied some Javascript (using the [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) function) which adds the id "page_template" to the radio button that has been selected.